# Log level in tests for PlayFramwork 1.x

Tags: log4j, playframework

When I launch my tests in localhost:9000/@tests# in console I can see long-long log with DEBUG log-level. I want to get rid of that. I tried to put to my application.conf

line like:

```
application.log=INFO
```

or even this line:

```
application.log.system.out=off
```

But it does not work. Maybe I should put log4j setting specially for test context somehow..?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply prefix those two rules with the "test" id.

```
%test.application.log.system=off
%test.application.log=ERROR
```

And by the way log levels are : `trace` -> `debug` -> `info` -> `warn` -> `error` -> `fatal`

So when displaying `info`, you are displaying a lot of information.

Comment: Is this `%test` stuff documented anywhere? Does it work for Play 2.x?

Comment: No, this doesn't work for Play2. This was a Play1. specification.

Answer (score 0):

What's your log4j.properties configuration? Most likely you have Debug enabled in there.

If you have this setting enabled:

```
   application.log.path=/log4j.properties
```

try to disable it and run the tests to verify this is changing the logs. If that's the issue then modify that line to:

```
  %test.application.log.path=/log4j-test.properties
  %dev.application.log.path=/log4j-dev.properties
```

and create the 2 versions of log4j.properties, so you have the right logging level in each.