# Remove the DEBUG-messages when testing a Play-SolrJ-Application

Tags: logging, solr, playframework, logback, playframework-2.1

My Scala-application uses Play Framework 2.1 together with SolrJ (V. 4.0) to communicate with Solr.

- When I run my *tests* (`play test`) I get a very long annoying list of `DEBUG org.apache.http.*` messages from SolrJ. :-(
- When I *run* my application (`play run`) no debug-message from SolrJ appears. :-)

In `conf/application.conf` all logger levels are set to INFO:

```
logger.root=INFO
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=INFO
```

I even try to create my own `conf/application-logger.xml` file, but the DEBUG-messages from Solrj stay the same.

**How can I get rid of the DEBUG-messages durring testing?**

I have read an [old Stackoverflow-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992945/playframework-log-level-in-tests) about this, but the answers don't work (I think it was a question for Play 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the log level dynamically in your Java code.

```
 private static void modifyLogLevel() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Enumeration<Logger> e = Logger.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        Logger curLogger = e.nextElement();
        if (curLogger.getName().contains("org.apache")){
            curLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        }
    }
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("log4j.logger.org.apache","ERROR");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response (I get ill). The idea is good, I will test it as sonn as I get to work again.

Comment: Finally I found out that I "forgot" an old `logback-test.xml` in my classpath that overwrites the settings from `conf/application.conf`.